# How to scrape second column from table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from second column of table but failed...

Here is my code:

```
import bs4
import requests 
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom"`

data=requests.get(url)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
#print(My_table)
My_row = My_table.find_all('tr')
#print(My_row[1])
for row in My_row:
   data= (row.find('td')[1].text)
   print(data)
```

Here is error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

What will be the best solution?

Comment: The problem is here: `data= (row.find('td')[1].text)`: "row.find(td)" doesn't return an array.  Q: What is your Python debugger or IDE?  SUGGESTION: 1) refactor your code, to `rowdata = row.find('td')`, 2) Set a breakpoint, then 3) determine exactly what "type" rowdata is?

Comment: @paulsm4 I am using Spyder

Answer (score 0):

You can use read_html from pandas

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom')
print(tables[1][1])
```

All 4 columns use:

```
print(tables[1])
```

It's a dataframe so you can slice as required. It returns [1503 rows x 4 columns]

Comment: in this way, we are not getting all data.

Comment: you want one column right? Otherwise use print(tables[1]) for loop i.e. for table in tables:

Comment: I want column two data

Comment: use  print(tables[1])

Comment: We are not getting completely data because of first column. Is any other method to get only second column data?

Comment: Please explain? This returns [1503 rows x 4 columns]

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work

```
import bs4
import requests

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom"

data = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    if i > 0:
        for j, td in enumerate(row.children):
            if j == 3:
                print(td.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Beautiful Soup (4.7+) use a package called Soup Sieve which provides the selector support. I personally find CSS selectors easier to use for these kinds of things. You can check out all the CSS selector features it supports here: https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/.

This problem is actually really easy with selectors. It would be even easier if CSS level 4 `:nth-col` support was implemented, but it is still pretty easy without:

Here we simply target the table and target every second `td` element in every row.

```
import bs4
import requests

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom"

data = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

for td in soup.select('table.wikitable.sortable tr td:nth-child(2)'):
    print(td.text.strip())
```

Truncated output:

```
AB10, AB11, AB12, AB15, AB16, AB21, AB22, AB23, AB24, AB25, AB99non-geo
AB13
AB14
AB30
AB31
AB32
AB33
AB34
AB35
AB36
AB37
AB38
AB39
AB41
AB42
AB43
AB44
AB45
AB51
AB52
AB53
AB54
AB55
AB56
AL01 AL1, AL2, AL3, AL4
AL05 AL5
AL06 AL6, AL7shared
AL07 AL7shared, AL8
AL09 AL9, AL10
B001 B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, B10, B11, B12, B13, B14, B15, B16, B17, B18, B19, B20, B21, B23, B24, B25, B26, B27, B28, B29, B30, B31, B32, B33, B34, B35, B36, B37, B38, B40, B42, B43, B44, B45, B46, B47, B48,B99non-geo
B049 B49, B50
```

Comment: This is with BeautifulSoup 4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.It should work.It will return the second column text.

```
import bs4
import requests
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_districts_in_the_United_Kingdom"

data=requests.get(url)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
My_row = My_table.find_all('tr')
for row in My_row:
   data= row.find_next('td').find_next('td')
   print(data.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
AB10, AB11, AB12, AB15, AB16, AB21, AB22, AB23, AB24, AB25, AB99non-geo
AB10, AB11, AB12, AB15, AB16, AB21, AB22, AB23, AB24, AB25, AB99non-geo
AB13
AB14
AB30
AB31
AB32
AB33
AB34
AB35
AB36
AB37
AB38
AB39
AB41
AB42
AB43
AB44
AB45
AB51
AB52
AB53
AB54
AB55
AB56
AL01 AL1, AL2, AL3, AL4
AL05 AL5
AL06 AL6, AL7shared
AL07 AL7shared, AL8
AL09 AL9, AL10
B001 B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, B10, B11, B12, B13, B14, B15, B16, B17, B18, B19, B20, B21, B23, B24, B25, B26, B27, B28, B29, B30, B31, B32, B33, B34, B35, B36, B37, B38, B40, B42, B43, B44, B45, B46, B47, B48,B99non-geo
B049 B49, B50
B060 B60, B61
B062 B62, B63
B064 B64
B065 B65
B066 B66, B67
B068 B68, B69
B070 B70, B71
B072  B72, B73, B74, B75, B76
B077 B77, B78, B79
B080 B80
B090 B90, B91, B92, B93, B94
B095 B95
B096 B96, B97, B98
BA01 BA1, BA2
BA03 BA3
BA04 BA4
BA05 BA5
BA06 BA6
BA07 BA7
BA08 BA8
BA09 BA9shared
BA09 BA9,non-geo shared[2] BA10
BA11
BA12
BA13
BA14
BA15
BA16
BA20, BA21, BA22
BB01 BB1, BB2, BB6
BB03 BB3
BB04 BB4
BB05 BB5
BB07 BB7
BB08 BB8
BB09 BB9
BB10, BB11, BB12
BB18, BB94non-geo
BD01 BD1, BD2, BD3, BD4, BD5, BD6, BD7, BD8, BD9, BD10, BD11, BD12, BD13, BD14, BD15, BD98,non-geo shared BD99non-geo
BD16, BD97non-geo
BD17, BD18, BD98non-geo shared
BD19
BD20, BD21, BD22
BD23, BD24shared
BD24shared
BF01 BF1non-geo
BH01 BH1, BH2, BH3, BH4, BH5, BH6, BH7, BH8, BH9, BH10, BH11
BH12, BH13, BH14, BH15, BH16, BH17
BH18
BH19
BH20
BH21
BH22
BH23
BH24
BH25
BH31
BL00 BL0,
```